# Why does the volume bar keep popping up in the active display in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

Why does the volume bar keep popping up in the active display in 16.04? Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Is it showing changes in volume, or just showing up?

Comment: It just pops up at random about every 5 seconds give or take.